# : editing and closing a file in bash programmatically

Tags: bash, gedit

I have now succeeded in opening and changing a text file with gedit in a bash script. Now I need to save and close the editor. How do I go about it, please?

Comment: Don't use `gedit`. Use something designed to be run automatically. Like `sed` or `awk` or similar.

Comment: Or vim, see: [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467)

Comment: Or even `ed`, if you want to go old-school.  And if you can find a system that has it.

Comment: `ed` is part of the POSIX standard; it should be readily available.

Comment: @ Etan can you explain  why I shouldn't use gedit , please?

Comment: to close the file pkill  emacs or in my case of using gedit pkill gedit worked.